# Word-to-LaTeX converted table is misplaced, please help to fix the problem

Tags: tables, msword, word-to-latex

I've edited a table on Word in regard of its complication (mathematic formulas, merged cells...) and I've converted it to LaTeX version with GrindEQ Math Word-to-LaTeX converter. The problem is that the code does not give a suitable look on my LaTeX paper. The table is horizontal while my paper is in portrait mode, that's why the table exceeds the page limits. I want it to have the same width as the paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1in}|p{0.6in}|p{1.0in}|p{0.6in}|p{1.0in}|p{0.6in}|p{0.3in}|p{1.0in}|p{0.6in}|p{1.0in}|} \hline 
& \textbf{BANK} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{\textbf{Participant 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{\textbf{Participant 2}} & \textbf{\dots } & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{\textbf{Participant (n-1)}} & \textbf{Participant n} \\ \hline 
& \textbf{Investing option} & \textbf{Take-up option} & \textbf{Investing option} & \textbf{Take-up option} & \textbf{Investing option} & \textbf{\dots } & \textbf{Take-up option} & \textbf{Investing option} & \textbf{Investing option} \\ \hline 
\textbf{T${}_{1}$} & $C\times (n+1)$\textit{} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{$-\ C$\textit{}} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{$-\ C$\textit{}} & \textit{\dots } & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{$-\ C$\textit{}} & $-\ C$\textit{} \\ \hline 
\textbf{T${}_{2}$} & $-\ C$\textit{} & $C\times (n+1)\times (1-w_1)$\textit{} & $-\ C$\textit{} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{$-\ C$\textit{}} & \textit{\dots } & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{$-\ C$\textit{}} & $-\ C$\textit{} \\ \hline 
\textbf{T${}_{3}$} & $-\ C$\textit{} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{$-\ C$\textit{}} & $C\times (n+1)\times (1-w_2)$\textit{} & $-\ C$\textit{} & \textit{\dots } & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{$-\ C$\textit{}} & $-\ C$\textit{} \\ \hline 
\textbf{\dots } & \textit{\dots } & \textit{\dots } & \textit{\dots } & \textit{\dots } & \textit{\dots } & \textit{} & \textit{\dots } & \textit{\dots } & \textit{\dots } \\ \hline 
\textbf{T${}_{n}$} & $-\ C$\textit{} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{$-\ C$\textit{}} & \multicolumn{2}{|p{1.6in}|}{$-\ C$\textit{}} & \textit{\dots } & $C\times (n+1)\times (1-w_{n-1})$\textit{} & $-\ C$\textit{} & $-\ C$\textit{} \\ \hline 
\textbf{T${}_{n+1}$} & $-\ C$\textit{} & $-\ C+[C\times (n+1)\times w_1]$\textit{} & $-\ C$\textit{} & $-\ C+[C\times (n+1)\times w_2]$\textit{} & $-\ C$\textit{} & \textit{\dots } & $-\ C+[C\times (n+1)\times w_{n-1}]$\textit{} & $-\ C$\textit{} & $C\times (n+1)$\textit{} \\ \hline 
\textbf{Capital at the end of the cycle} & $\left[C\times (n+1)\times \left(1+r\right)\right]+[C\times \left(n+1\right)\times \sum^n_{i=1}{{(1+rq}_n})]$\textit{} & $C\times (n+1)$\textit{} & $\left[C\times (n+1)\times \left(1+rp_1\right)\right]$\textit{} & $C\times (n+1)$\textit{} & $\left[C\times (n+1)\times \left(1+rp_2\right)\right]$\textit{} & \textit{\dots } & $C\times (n+1)$\textit{} & $\left[C\times n\times \left(1+rp_{n-1}\right)\right]$\textit{} & $\left[C\times (n+1)\times \left(1+rp_n\right)\right]$\textit{} \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Here is a screenshot of the Word table.
[image]

Comment: Could you the LaTeX code produced by GrindEQ &c.?

Comment: I've edited my original post, now it contains the code :-) @Bernard

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to make such a table fit a standard portrait page. Would you consider printing it in landscape? Another solution would to swap rows and columns. A thirs solution might be to print the very long formula in the second column as a footnote at the bottom of the table.

Comment: I would have liked to print it in landscape as an appendex, but unfortunately, the table has to be considered on the body text. I've already  swapped rows and columns, the table width becomes bigger. The best solution is to set a \tiny size for the hole table (at least for the formulas) if you can help @Bernard
thanks in advance.

Comment: How can the best solution be to make your table illegible? If it doesn't matter whether people can read it, it shouldn't be included at all. If the information is needed, it has to be readable. Can't you print it in landscape but not as an appendix?

Comment: I've solved the problem @Bernard it was just a matter of spacing of columns. I adjusted sizes and now it fits well on my paper.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP found a solution to his problem in the comments.

Comment: @Mico Go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses

- the `rotating` package and its `sidewaystable` environment to place the tabular material in landscape mode,
- the `tabularx` package and its `tabularx` package to allow automatic line-wrapping in each of the 8 main data columns,
- the `ragged2e` package and its `\Centering` macro to create a centered version of the `X` column type that allows hyphenation (if needed),
- the `booktabs` package and its line-drawing macros (`\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, `\cmidrule` and `\addlinespace`), along with a complete absence of any vertical rules, to give the table an "open" look, and
- the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages to render six of the cells in a soft gray.

With this setup, it's no longer necessary to crane one's neck repeatedly when moving from the upper to the lower portions of the table.

Observe that I've done away with all **bold-facing** -- it's simply not needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\newcommand\abtimes{\allowbreak\times}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % center cell contents vertically
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{0.8in} *{5}{C} c *{3}{C} @{} P{1sp} @{}}
\toprule
& Bank
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Participant 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Participant 2}
& $\cdots$
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Participant $n-1$}  & Participant $n$ & \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-10}
& Investing option
& Take-up option & Investing option
& Take-up option & Investing option
& $\cdots$
& Take-up option & Investing option
& Investing option & \\
\midrule
$T_{1}$ & $C\abtimes (n+1)$
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$-C$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$-C$} 
& $\cdots$
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$-C$}  & $-C$ & \\ \addlinespace
$T_{2}$ & $-C$
& \cellcolor{Snow2} $C\abtimes(n+1)\abtimes(1-w_1)$
& \cellcolor{Snow2} $-C$
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$-C$} & $\cdots$
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$-C$} & $-C$ & \\ \addlinespace
$T_{3}$ & $-C$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$-C$} 
& \cellcolor{Snow2} $C\abtimes (n+1)\abtimes (1-w_2)$
& \cellcolor{Snow2} $-C$ & $\cdots$
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$-C$}  & $-C$ \\
$\vdots$ & & & & & & $\vdots$ \\
$T_{n}$  & $-C$
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$-C$}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$-C$}  & $\cdots$
& \cellcolor{Snow2} $C\abtimes (n+1)\abtimes (1-w_{n-1})$
& \cellcolor{Snow2} $-C$ & $-C$ & \\\addlinespace\addlinespace
$T_{n+1}$ & $-C$
& $-C+[C\times (n+1)\abtimes w_1]$ & $-C$
& $-C+[C\times (n+1)\abtimes w_2]$ & $-C$ & $\cdots$
& $-C+[C\times (n+1)\abtimes w_{n-1}]$ & $-C$
& $C\abtimes (n+1)$ & \\ \addlinespace\addlinespace
Capital at end of cycle
& $[C\abtimes (n+1)\abtimes (1+r)]+\allowbreak[C\times (n+1)\abtimes \sum^n_{i=1}(1+rq_n)]$
& $C\abtimes (n+1)$
& $C\abtimes (n+1)\abtimes (1+rp_1)$
& $C\abtimes (n+1)$ & $C\abtimes (n+1) \abtimes (1+rp_2)$
& $\cdots$
& $C\abtimes (n+1)$ & $C\abtimes (n+1) \abtimes (1+rp_{n-1})$
& $C\abtimes (n+1)\abtimes (1+rp_n)$ & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```